# How to add Custom Css within the Editor?

Tags: customization, css

I've been struggling for a while with this one.

I am trying to target an element within a column or block, in this case the 'Submit' button of a WPForm.

So I open the developer tools in Firefox, select my element and get the class name:

```
<button type="submit" name="wpforms[submit]" id="wpforms-submit-863" class="wpforms-submit" data-alt-text="Sending..." data-submit-text="Submit" aria-live="assertive" value="wpforms-submit">Submit</button>
```

Now, in the editor I select the form (or column) and add the following to the custom CSS section:

```
.button[type="submit"] {
  background: yellow;
}
```

I've tried `wpforms-submit` and other variations however, nothing happens and it's not the first time. I think I just don't understand something about the logic or nesting or else.

How do I target an element with custom CSS in the Editor?

Comment: if you're using the block editor you can add a custom class in the sidebar under the advanced panel, otherwise you'll need to speak with WP Forms support, 3rd party plugin dev support questions are off topic here. Also just because you added a CSS rule doesn't mean that rule is the most specific, your browsers dev tools can show you if the rule is applied and if it was overridden by a more specific rule, but that's a generic CSS question and WP knowledge is not useful for that

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote it seems you might need to look at CSS Specificity... Which in short means: the more specific the CSS selector is, it has more value and therefore it will be used instead of the weaker one. (You can learn more about it for example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).)

Plugins usually use more complex and specific selectors, so you need to make sure you will make your selectors stronger in order to override the initial style. Basically you have several ways:

1. Make the selector more specific
2. Use the very same selector, but place it later in the code
3. Use `!important` flag in the definition (better use only in desperate cases)

Also it seems WPForms offer to set specific classes to the elements (check [here](https://wpforms.com/docs/how-to-add-custom-css-to-your-wpforms/)). Using those classes in your selectors will probably make them more specific and therefore they will override the initial ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer `!important` does work, however, the correct selector is `selector button[type='submit']`. `selector` is apparently necessary.

Comment: Yes, the best is to first use developer tools to find out under which selector the style is originally defined and use the same selector or stronger. In case of WPForms the initial one may be something like ".wpforms-form button[type='submit']", so simply "button[type='submit']" would not be enough to override it.